# jquery error placement

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, validation

i've a jquery form. the validations work correctly but i'd like the error to be placed properly. right now it displays in IE 7 as:

[alt text http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/1810/errorhma.jpg](http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/1810/errorhma.jpg)

but i'd like to display it as:

[alt text http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/7089/error1ace.jpg](http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/7089/error1ace.jpg)

this is the css code:

```
div.error { display:none; }
           <%-- input { border: 1px solid black; }--%>
            input:focus { border: 1px dotted black; }
            input.error { border: 2px solid red; }
            label.error { color: white; font-size:16px; font-family:Nyala; background-color: red }
            label.valid { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try label.error{display:block;}

Answer (score 3):

You can control the placement of the error message with errorPlacement. Default value is "error.insertAfter( element )". You can use one of these for example:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertBefore( element );
    //error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    //error.appendTo(label.insertAfter( element ));
    //error.insertAfter(element.sibling(a));
}
```

or even put here some condition and use other statements:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(".something") ) {
        element.nextAll('div').html(error);
    } else {
        error.insertAfter( element );
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues, the first is that the error coloring is shown as surrounding the input element element. So either you need to use the error div to contain the input element or just change the color of the container for the form element. I'm voting for changing the color of the container.

Second, you want the div.error to be clear on the left and right (*assuming you're just changing the color of the container for the form element*), so just add:

```
div.error {
  clear: both;
}
```

This assumes of course that for some reason you've floated it to the left. In any case, see a simple example of what one way to lay it out

http://jsbin.com/amaxa